# Demangle c++ functions in radare2

Tags: radare2

I am learning radare2. Is there a way to demangle c++ functions during disassembling? For example in gdb

```
set print asm-demangle
```

changes

```
callq 0x400a30 <_ZNSo3putEc@plt>
```

to

```
callq 0x400a30 <_std::ostream::put(char)@plt>
```

edit:
I had radare2 0.9.6 which comes with Ubuntu's synaptic package manager. I reinstalled it from https://github.com/radare/radare2. Now I see the `asm.demangle` variable after entering `Ve`, it is set to true, but names are still mangled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `e asm.demangle`, and set it to true or false as required.

Is the radare2 version you are using the latest one?

You should be able to view all the configuration data with `e`.

Typing `e??` should show you a complete list of configuration variables with their description. You can grep through the output for all the vars that have the pattern *demangle* with

```
[0x00001d52]> e??~demangle
        asm.demangle: Show demangled symbols in disasm
        bin.demangle: Import demangled symbols from RBin
            bin.lang: Language for bin.demangle
[0x00001d52]>
```

Radare2 needs to be told to load the demangle informations at startup, so you can set `bin.demangle` to `true`, and reopen the file:

```
 e bin.demangle = true
 oo
```

Last but not least, you can provide a symbol name in its mangled form on a case by case basis, using the command `iD`:

```
[0x7c810705]> iD cxx _ZNSo3putEc
std::ostream::put
[0x7c810705]>
```

By the way, a tip instead of asking a question here and waiting forever:
radare2 is self documented, so you can begin by typing `?` to get help, and then append `?` to each command, like `a?`, or `pd?` and so on…

Comment: Sorry, but how? If I enter `e asm.demangle=true`, I get: variable 'asm.demangle' not found